# Why are there questions with answers in "UNANSWERED QUESTIONS"

Tags: discussion

I check the unanswered questions category and there are some questions with answers, why is this?[image]

The two bottom questions are answered

Comment: Because of poorly chosen words. "Unanswered" should really be something like "unresolved". Yes, I think it's silly too that "unanswered" questions sometimes have non-zero answers (duh).  Someone didn't think about this very hard when they came up with the naming scheme.

Comment: @OlinLathrop that's confusing but actually it's logic. If you ask me what color is the sky, and I tell you "use a triac", that didn't really answer your question, which is technically still "unanswered".

Comment: @clabacchio: "Answered" can also mean that a answer was provided.  That is how the OP is interpreting it, and how I also interpreted it when I first came to this site.  The english word *answered* can mean both *the question is not resolved* or *no answer was provided*.  A better choice of words would fix this confusion.  In your triac example, actually the question was answered (by one interpretation of "answered"), only that the answer wasn't useful.